# Upload products to amazon and retrive/import/export/ orders from amazon to own store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, e-commerce, php4

My company is using oscommerce 2.2ms and php 4. We want to upload our products to amazon shop. We have found magnalister and holbi connectors that we want to use but we cannot because we aere running php version 4.

So, I decide to create my own connector having these featurs:

- Upload products from my shop to the marketplace
- import orders from the marketplaces
- Synchronise order status between shop and marketplace
- Manage orders, invoices and export to my site

The Problem is:

1.) There are huge of api's that i cannot understand which is for what, so i little bit confused.

2.) I tried to use this [Api](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library), but this retrive all products that are avilable on amazon(searched catorgory).

Question  is: Which Api i have to use ?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP _**4.9**_!? First of all, that doesn't seem to exist. Secondly, PHP 5 came out in 2004. The last version of PHP 4 was version [4.4.9](https://secure.php.net/releases/#4.4.9), which [reached end of life in August, 2008](https://secure.php.net/eol.php). It is _very_ out of date, and likely suffers from _many_ unfixed security bugs.

Comment: @Chris i am new to my company they have just assume me 20 days ago and i know they are using php 4. neither i dont know how old is my company lol. Can you tell me which api can help me. this is php info 
img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/29/57c49dd8ca0c1.png